# Character limit in string variables

Tags: spss

when I export my data from a .dta file to .sps, my string variables get cut off and the data contains signs, which look like a UTF-8 problem. I think, the problem might be that some string variables have a width over 261- at least they are cut at that point.

Does SPSS have a character limit, and if so, how can I increase the number?

Comment: SPSS has a very generous limit when it comes to string width. The problem might be in your original data source. But it is not clear to me if you are referring to string variables or to variable labels. Files with .sps extension are not data files

Answer (score 0):

"The values of string variables can contain numbers, letters, and special characters and can be up to [32,767 bytes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_variables_string_variable_formats.html). "

You seem to be trying to export [STATA](https://www.stata.com/) data (*.sta) to SPSS Statistics (*.sav).  What mechanism are you using in STATA to do this?  Does STATA have a limitation on the width of string fields?

As horace_vr has already pointed out, an SPSS Statistics command file has the *.sps extension.  Are you truly trying to have STATA write SPSS Statistics Command Syntax for you and save as *.sps?  Perhaps you meant you were exporting from *.dta (in STATA) to *.sav (in SPSS Statistics).

Note also that if you have created an SPSS Statistics data file (*.sav) in Codepage mode, but then open it while SPSS Statistics is in Unicode mode, your string widths will triple in size.  This is an artifact of the conversion of the various codepages to unicode.

"[When code page data files are read in Unicode mode, the defined width of all string variables is tripled.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_set_unicode.html) You can use ALTER TYPE to automatically adjust the width of all string variables."

I hope this helps 
-ddwyer